# macOS 13.2 UITextField misalignment when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mac-catalyst

The test field was originally centered. However, as I tap on it, it was brought to the left.

This UI issue occurs on macOS 13.2, built on My Mac(Designed for iPad), while running on iPad is totally fine.
Xcode 14.2 and 14.1 has the same behaviour.

[image: misaligned]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let textField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.backgroundColor = .green
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        textField.text = "Hello, World"
        return textField
    }()
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(textField)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
        
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Got answered in [Apple dev forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/725769). It's a bug that will be fixed in macOS 13.3